# Alert if save name doesn't match filename

Tags: excel, vba, autosave

I am working on an excel form that saves the workbook every entry with a name from a certain cell.  I have that part working fine but have found that if I start one and save it, then continue on it and change that cell value I will overwrite the existing file with that cell value name.  I do not want this to happen.  Is there a way I can have it check to see if the active filename is the same as that cell value before it will allow the workbook to save. Here is all the code to help see what it does. I would think putting it all in an If statement would be the way to go but I am not sure.  Excuse my no coding skills

```
 Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()
    'Unprotect QCS sheet
    Sheets("QCS").Unprotect Password:="1234"
    
    'Copy input values to sheet QCS
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("QCS")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Range("Home!B1")
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Range("Home!B2")
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Range("Home!B4")
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Range("Home!B3")
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.txtRollNumber.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cboTreatment.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.cboTensions.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.txtWidth.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.txtBasisWeight.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.txtSlip.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.txtHaze.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.txtOpacity.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Me.txtGloss.Value
        
    End With
    'Clear input controls.
    Me.txtRollNumber.Value = ""
    Me.cboTreatment.Value = ""
    Me.cboTensions.Value = ""
    Me.txtWidth.Value = ""
    Me.txtBasisWeight.Value = ""
    Me.txtSlip.Value = ""
    Me.txtHaze.Value = ""
    Me.txtOpacity.Value = ""
    Me.txtGloss.Value = ""
    
    
    'Save the Workbook as excel doc.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String
    Path = "C:\Users\121375\Documents\QCSTrial\"
    filename = Range("Home!B2")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".xlsm"
    
    'Save QCS Sheet as PDF
    'Create and assign variables
    Dim saveLocation As String
    Dim sheetArray As Variant

    saveLocation = "C:\Users\121375\Documents\QCSTrial\" & filename & ".xlsm"
    sheetArray = Array("QCS")

    'Select specific sheets from workbook, the save all as PDF
    Sheets(sheetArray).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:=saveLocation
    
    'Close Form.
    Unload Me
    
    'Protect Sheet Again.
    Sheets("QCS").Protect Password:="1234"
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not clear (at least, for me) what you want accomplishing. Since the `SaveAs` uses the value of cell "B2" of the "Home" sheet, how to overwrite the active workbook? It will obviously create a new workbook with that specific name. Which is, in fact, the problem you want avoiding? All the time when use `SaveAs` a new workbook is created, using the cell "B2" value. I cannot understand the scenario you try describing. What does **if I start one and save it, then continue on it ** means? Is the problem in the code you show, or it is connected somehow with the saving itself?

Comment: So this will be used to record quality checks, the filename will be the order number.  So when the form is entered it pulls the order number from that cell and saves the file. Naturally that is now the open workbook. Now say somebody changes the order number to an order that has already been entered and fills out the form again.  That order that was already entered is now overwritten.  Was wondering if there was a way to make the form not save if the order number cell and the active filename do not match and if not give a message to close the workbook.

Comment: Can you better explain what does "overwritten" means for you? Like I said, the `SaveAs` method creates a new workbook with the name taken from "B1" cell. Do you mean avoiding to save if a workbook having the name like in "B2" already exists? What does **the same as that cell value before** should mean? Do you mean something like "it has been saved once in the past"? Anyhow, if you try saving over an existing workbook, Excel will worn about that and ask if you want overwriting it. Do you want refusing to save without asking for overwriting, to avoid the user pressing OK when asked about that?

Comment: I think you need to catch the duplicate before it gets entered onto the worksheet. Something like `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B:B"), Range("Home!B2")) > 0 Then Exit Sub` maybe.

Comment: I have made a workaround.  Since this workbook was going to be opened from a separate workbook, I was able to link Cell B2 to the filename on the template, and then have my launcher workbook create a file based on the template and give it the name needed.  Sorry if that doesn't make sense.  May not of been the easiest way around the problem but I have it working 100% of the time now.  Basically right now we have no IT support to create apps for us so I am using excel to try and get things done.

Comment: Why not add an increasing number to the filename?